# How to handle different chart types as per user input in JasperReports jrxml file

Tags: jasper-reports

I am facing a problem, while creating the report user can say generate BAR chart or generate PIE chart or generate TIMELINE chart.

I don't want to write different jrxml files for each type of charts and invoke them from code depending on the type of chart selected. But write all these charts in same jrxml file and 
fill charts depending on user selection.

I thought of using printwhenexpression. but not able to succeed in using it.

I can pass the user selection in paramerter map.

Is there any way to do conditioning in jrxml for different chart types?

Comment: yes, you can provide chartName information via PARAMETER and then use printWhenExpression in jrxml. I hope this will give you some idea.

Comment: Yeah. I was able to use printwhenexpression :) I was adding the expression in the wrong place.

Comment: Then you should add plus point to comment :)